# Perspective API in Android

Tags: android

Ive been trying to use Perspective API ( https://www.perspectiveapi.com/#/home)  in my Android app but for some reason, i keep getting 404 after calling https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments/analyze?key=...

Did anyone was able to integrate this API in their app?

Thanks

Comment: I see a double quote (") in your googleapis endpoint link. Just making sure that was a copy error and not in your code.

Comment: Copy error :) i fixed the question.